# Nginx image path correction on rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Not 100% sure if this is a Nginx error or a set-up error.

Playing around with re-writes as I've never been too great with them and I'd managed to get it so once something on `/profile/.*` would go through a PHP file and handle the request_uri.

Works great, does its job but all the assets such as images stop because it's trying to load them from `/profile/dist/img/...` instead of `/dist/img/...`which causes it to 404.

Do I need to catch this within in Nginx so any image file types are explicitly told to look in that a set folder or is it the way the files/structure are set up?

My re-write is :

```
location /profile/ {
       rewrite ^/profile/(.*) /profile_handler.php?url=$1;
    }
```

Even though the re-write file in profile_handler.php is on the root folder and it references a header and footer both on the root folder, all the  tags are trying /profile/img.

I've tried

```
 location ~ ^/profile/img/(.*) {
  try_files $uri /img/$uri;
}
```

but i cant get it to work.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your rewrite rules, so that image requests are not sent to PHP.  It's not that PHP isn't able to handle those, but it's a waste of time, no?   Please show your rewrite rules so that we can see how they can be improved.

Comment: I've put my rewrite into edit, just for reference my rewrite is targeted at no file type as some of the custom URLs don't contain.html and are just text strings

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to match /profile/img when you say the image URL's are like /dist/img/...

Comment: yeah my apologies, thought it was dist/imgs but on inspection it turned out to be /img

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl:

```
location /dist/img/ {
   try_files $uri =404;
}

location /profile/ {
   rewrite ^/profile/(.*) /profile_handler.php?url=$1;
}
```

Comment: What would this achieve? would this not just continue to 404 non foundsfiles ?

Comment: ???  Only if they really do not exist (on your system).  Haven't you got a system on which to try it out?  Have you checked the syntax of try_files when you wrote your rule?

Comment: I'm testing it on a development server so i can try it out, I'm not really confident with nginx as of yet, how would I go about testing / checking the syntax

Comment: Just make a number of requests against that server and see what happens.  And nginx checks the syntax.  Your try_files passed the syntax check - but I would be very surprised if it did what you intended.  Look at the meaning of the last value in a try_files.

Comment: Can see this being an in your face answer I'm not spotting, thanks for the help and ill read up on it now

Comment: Sorry if I insulted you.   I often do.

Comment: Nah don't worry about it, its something i've been meaning to learn properly and this seems like a common thing which will come up so i'll need to learn how to do it properly anyway

Comment: Ah, the pot and the kettle.  I've made a "little" correction to the last value of my try_files.